# snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.51: Invalid acp audio mode: 1 (Lenovo IdeaPad 330S 15")

Tags: boot, lenovo, 19.04, ideapad

When I run Ubuntu 19.04, I see in the black screen output

```
[   16.546544] snd_pci_acp3x 0000:03:00.51: Invalid acp audio mode: 1
```

How do I fix this?

My PC is a Lenovo IdeaPad 330S 15" with an AMD Ryzen 5 2500U.

Comment: I have the same with an AMD Ryzen (either a 3 or 5) CPU. Have you found any solution?

Comment: Running Arch Linux on an IdeaPad L340 (Ryzen 5 3500U). I see this as well with no answers yet.

Comment: I just install the last ubuntu version (20.04.01) and all works well

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem for some days now when I finally decided to look into it myself. I have an AMD Ryzen 5 4600H chipset and the ACP that is causing problems was not needed for me since newer Renoir processors use `snd_rn_pci_acp3x` sound drivers and not `snd_pci_acp3x`. But, for you the problem is basically with Audio Co-processor's(ACP's) version incompatibility. You can know more about AMD's ACP driver from [here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Linux-ACP-Audio). Since the error is harmless you can simply blacklist the drivers in `modprobe` configuration file.
For this open a new terminal instance and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add the following line at the end of the file,

```
blacklist snd_pci_acp3x
```

Save the file and thats it, now just do a `sudo reboot` and the error should be gone now.